# Issues with jScroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I'm attempting to use jScroll to load a partial view repeatedly, based on an incrementing page number. This partial view gets back a few divs, nothing special. In order to have infinite scrolling, the partial view must return the hyperlink tag in order to allow itself to find the next page to load (as far as I am aware, at least.)

So we have the partial view,

Partial View:

```
    <div class="someClass"></div>
    <div class="someOtherClass"></div>
    <a class="jScroll-next" href="some/path/to/resource?pagenumber=1">
```

The view in which the partial view is placed repeatedly,

View:

```
<div id="PrimaryDiv">
@PartialView 
</div>
```

And the jQuery that helps power and link it all together.

jQuery:

```
    $(document).ready(function (){

    var pn = 1;

    function incrementAndSet(){
        pn +=1;
        $('.jScroll-next').prop("href","some/path/to/resource?pagenumber=" + pn);
    }

        $(#PrimaryDiv).jscroll({
            autoTrigger: true,
            nextSelector: '.jScroll-next',
            callBack: function(){incrementAndSet();}
        });
     });
```

My issue is that, even though the next link is being populated, it's not being used. Example output:

1st scroll:

```
<div id="PrimaryDiv">
    <div class="someClass">datavalueforpage1</div>
    <div class="someOtherClass">somedataonpage1</div>
    <a class="jScroll-next" href="some/path/to/resource?pagenumber=2">
</div>
```

2nd scroll:

```
<div id="PrimaryDiv">
    <div class="someClass">datavalueforpage1</div>
    <div class="someOtherClass">somedataonpage1</div>
    <div class="someClass">datavalueforpage1</div>
    <div class="someOtherClass">somedataonpage1</div>
    <a class="jScroll-next" href="some/path/to/resource?pagenumber=3">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out a solution part way through the post, thought I'd share it anyway.

It was mostly me derping on scope. Moving:

```
var pn = 1;
```

and

```
function incrementAndSet(){
```

outside of the

```
    $(document).ready(function (){
```

allowed me to utilize the counter (pn) in the

```
    $(document).ready(function (){
```

of the partial view, meaning I could call the `incrementAndSet()`function on the partial view, ensuring that the data was properly set when the partial view was ready.

So my files look similar to this:

Partial View:

```
.../Partial.js

<div class="someClass"></div>
<div class="someOtherClass"></div>
<a class="jScroll-next" href="some/path/to/resource?pagenumber=1">
```

Parent View:

```
.../Parent.js

<div id="PrimaryDiv">
@PartialView 
</div>
```

Partial jQuery file:

```
$(document).ready(function (){
    incrementAndSet();
    });
```

Parent jQuery file:

```
    var pn = 1;

    function incrementAndSet(){
        pn +=1;
        $('.jScroll-next').prop("href","some/path/to/resource?pagenumber=" + pn);
    }

    $(document).ready(function (){
        $(#PrimaryDiv).jscroll({
            autoTrigger: true,
            nextSelector: '.jScroll-next',
            callBack: function(){incrementAndSet();}
        });
     });
```